# angular with htmlcode5 for removal #

Tags: angularjs, api, url, hash

I've been trying to remove the hash for angular urls but with no luck. Tried searching everywhere but anything I use seems to fail
     var module = angular.module("App", ['ngRoute']);

```
module.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
           when('/route1', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'RouteController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    }]);

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

module.controller("RouteController", function($scope) {

})
```

This seems to have no effect on the url. I still get a 404 for index.html/route1
Ideally would like example.com/route1

Any help appreciated.

A further update to clarify. My file is app.html.

So **/app.html#/** is the current address. Ideally I would like this to be:
**/folder/**

I've trawled the web but none of the solutions seem to fit.

I tried [this solution here](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag).
But didn't work.

Comment: Further update - I have managed to get  **/folder/#/** to work but cannot remove the **#/** from the address bar. i.e. **/folder/** redirects to  **/folder/#/**  Any one there to help. Getting very frustrating.